# Boolean Event Handler property does not get called / how to proberly set it

Tags: c#, boolean

I want to do sth when my boolean has changed to true. I implemented this version

```
public bool NextW_method
{
  get { return NextWClicked; }
  set
  {
    if (NextWClicked == true && value == false)
    {
      if (Karm <= zahl)
      {
        NextWClicked = false;
        //do sth
      }
      else
      {
        NextWClicked = false;
       //do sth else
      }
      NextWClicked = value;
    }
  }
```

The bool variable is set to true but the change does not get recognized by the method. What did i do wrong?

**edit**
changed the way i access certain values and this question is not valid anymore

Comment: I don't see how it gets set to `true`, you only seem to handle the `false` case in your setter. It seems you might look for something like [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2), but you really wouldn't implement it that complex

Comment: It doesn't even call the method when debugging. I can understand why, as it is just a method and is never called by me. I found the same code on several sources and it worked there as it is, but not for me.... The INotifyPropertyChanged seems a lot to code just for a simple event on change....but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you cover other cases, than

```
if (NextWClicked == true && value == false)
```

Is you NextWClicked value set to "true" when you debug?

Try to cover all cases, adding "else" block to your property.

Comment: NextWClicked is set to true when it should be. I thought value meant the prev value so i am quite confused as to what value i should check

Comment: Ok, try then simple {get; set;} property then and check, if you even rich your property while debugging.

Comment: I dont know if my code is a property already.. i just wrote those lines of code. What i dont seem to understand is that the method gets never called

Comment: I added a debug flag thing in the code .. well several. In the bool check and in the code that should be called after the bool is true. But whenever the bool check should be called nothing happens